Resilience4j CircuitBreaker not going in half open state in server
I have circuitbreaker implemented in my springboot application. I have used following dependency:
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j'

And I have following properties configured for my testing:
resilience4j:
  circuitbreaker:
    instances:
      myEventCircuitBreaker:
        minimum-number-of-calls: 6
        failure-rate-threshold: 80
        automatic-transition-from-open-to-half-open-enabled: true
        wait-duration-in-open-state: 300s
        permitted-number-of-calls-in-half-open-state: 4
        sliding-window-size: 1000
        sliding-window-type: count_based

When I test in my local it works fine, where in case of exception after 6 events, circuit is opened.
And after 300seconds (5 minutes) circuitbreaker goes in half open state.
I have following logs configured:
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class CircuitBreakerConfig {

    private final BindingsLifecycleController bindingsLifecycleController;

    public CircuitBreakerConfig(CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry, BindingsLifecycleController bindingsLifecycleController) {
        this.bindingsLifecycleController = bindingsLifecycleController;
        CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = circuitBreakerRegistry.circuitBreaker("myEventCircuitBreaker");
        circuitBreaker.getEventPublisher()
            .onStateTransition(this::handleStateTransition);
    }

    private void handleStateTransition(CircuitBreakerOnStateTransitionEvent event) {
        String bindingName = "stockEventConsumer-in-0";
        switch (event.getStateTransition().getToState()) {
            case OPEN:
                log.info("circuitbreaker state:: open");
                bindingsLifecycleController.changeState(bindingName, State.PAUSED);
                break;
            case HALF_OPEN:
                log.info("circuitbreaker state:: half_open");
                bindingsLifecycleController.changeState(bindingName, State.RESUMED);
                break;
            case CLOSED:
                log.info("circuitbreaker state:: closed");
                bindingsLifecycleController.changeState(bindingName, State.RESUMED);
                break;
            default:
                log.error("circuitbreaker unknown state");
        }
    }
}

The issue what I am facing is when I deploy my code in my dev/ppe environment, after 6 events with exception I am getting circuit open log.
But after that its not moving to half open state, and I don't see any logs from the configuration.
I read somewhere to add aspectj dependency, and after adding that, still its not working in the dev/ppe environment. But working as expected in local.
    implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.7'
    implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.7'


getting same issue in local. not firing the event after state change close to open.

@Shakib Try the latest version of circuitbreaker, by default you don't get latest version
Check if this works for you
https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/2167
